# Is there a way to show that $\int_{\Bbb R_+} {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx - \int_{\Bbb R_-} {1 \over x^2 + y^2} = 0$ without calcuating the explicit values?

Tags: integration

Assume that you have two integrals

$$\int_0^\infty {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx$$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^0 {-1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx$$

and you want to show that

$$\int_0^\infty {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 {-1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx = \int_0^\infty {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx = 0.$$

You are allowed to assume that $(x, y) \neq 0$.

It's quite obvious that the two integrals have the same value, but one still has to show that they have a finite value, because $\infty - \infty$ is not defined.

Is there a way to prove this without explicitly calculating the values of the integrals?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: What should $\mathbb{R}_{\pm}$ mean in this context? You want to integrate with respect to $x,y$?

Comment: $\Bbb R_+ = (0, \infty), \Bbb R_- = (-\infty, 0)$.

Comment: Are you assuming $y \neq 0$?

Comment: @Borol Could you please specify your variable of integration in the first two integrals. It does not make sense at all.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question, sorry.

Comment: For $y \neq 0$, $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{2|y|},$$ which is not infinite.  Where are your infinities coming from?

Comment: Please read the question again. I know that I can calculate the value of the integrals, but I wondered if there was a way to show that they are finite without calculating their values.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes on this question at all. What did I do wrong?

Comment: To show convergence, use $$\frac1{x^2+y^2}\leqslant\frac1{y^2}\mathbf 1_{|x|\leqslant1}+\frac1{x^2}\mathbf 1_{|x|>1}$$ which shows that $$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+y^2}\leqslant\int_0^1\frac{dx}{y^2}+\int_1^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac1{y^2}+1$$ and the same bound holds for the integral on $(-\infty,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

For $y \ne 0$: $\int_{\Bbb R_+} {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx=\int_{0}^1 {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx+\int_{1}^{\infty} {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx$

The integral $ \int_{0}^1 {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx$ makes no problems.

We have ${1 \over x^2 + y^2} \le {1 \over x^2 }$ and $\int_{1}^{\infty} {1 \over x^2 } dx$ converges.

Hence  $\int_{\Bbb R_+} {1 \over x^2 + y^2} dx$ converges.

For $y = 0$: $\int_{\Bbb R_+} {1 \over x^2 } dx$ is divergent.